# How to wait until particular event happened in multiple tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

I have a web-service which can process multiple queries simultaneously. Each query starts asynchronous task by passing `id` to some executor like this:

```
Executor.Start(id).
```

`Start(string)` returns immediately. At some point executor signals via callback that the task with some id was completed. But I need to wait until the task initiated by query is completed, only after that web-service should send a response. How to implement this?

Is it okay to create `ManualResetEvent` for each query, add it to some tracker and call `Set()` when task with corresponding id is completed? Is it okay to store the collection of hundreds `ManualResetEvent`'s? I could write something like this:

```
if (!manualResetEvent.WaitOne(100000))
{

}
```

Comment: It sounds that you need a WCF async web-service here. Read more at [Implement Asych Service Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx)

Comment: The service should by synchronous... but inside async things happens... that's the problem... each service call starts a task and must wait for it's completion

Comment: Does `Executor.Start(id)` return a Task<T>?

Comment: BenCr Nope, it returns void.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments (the queries are not related and just finish independently)

Yes, you could use ManualResetEvents.

A nicer design (from a web application point of view) is to return immediately and using a java script timer, check the status of the job from time to time and report the result. That way the web page stays responsive and you could even allow the user to cancel the query if the server supports that.

Comment: but I need to release only the one thread with some id at a time when task is completed. And this is a web-service -> tons of queries. I don't know the exact count.

Comment: Let the main thread set the Semaphore and then wait for it. Each task should decrease the Semaphore. The main thread will then continue when it reaches zero (or a time-out occurs)

Comment: I need to make a response right after task is completed, I don't need to wait them all.

Comment: Are these queries dependent in any way?

Comment: Nope, they are independent.

Comment: Then why the synchronization? Just execute the task and wait for it.

Comment: The point here is that queries are synchronous (I should respond only when task started by query is completed), but they start tasks which are asynchronous.

Comment: Executor works in async way. It takes ids and sometimes says "I am done with id 545". The query which put task 545 must sleep until this very moment and respond to client only when executor is finished with this task.

Comment: I modified my answer to address these comments.